# Unable to import IDropdownOption when not using TypeScript

Tags: fluentui-react

Having a project here not using TypeScript and trying to implement a Dropdown.

But I fail importing the Dropdown Option. Like documented in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dropdown

```
import { Dropdown, DropdownMenuItemType, IDropdownStyles, IDropdownOption } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Dropdown';
```

It cannot find the IDropdownOption export. It does not exist in the JS file, but in the TypeScript file.

Does that mean TypeScript is mandatory?

Comment: You need to use `.ts` or `.tsx` extension because IDropdownOption is Typescript Interface.

Comment: Right on, silly me. Thanks.